# Enabling Pipe(|) functionality with Postfix for a .forward file

Tags: email, postfix, pipe, forwarding

I'm running into an issue trying to get pipe forwarding working on postfix.  Rather than running the script I'm intending to run, it's appending to my script.  Testing on other servers this seems to work fine which leads me to believe this is a configuration error I can't seem to find in my main.cf.

I did some searches and came up with being told I should add the F=| flag to my delivery agent but I'm unsure where I should be adding this.

Thanks!

Comment: Wow, what a bad question. Yes it is a configuration problem. Looking at your `.forward` file shows the error!

Comment: @mailq Uh.. did Justin post his `.forward` somewhere? [Not trolling]

Comment: But me. I was trolling. It should be ironic. How should we look into an issue by only saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: Not a bad question, the .forward file is fine as it works on other servers.  Bad assumption is more like it.  If the forward file was bad, it wouldn't be writing to the file.  In this case, my mail message is being appended to /home/username/email-filter.php.  Just to appease though, here's my .forward file

| /usr/bin/php /home/username/email-filter.php

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the `allow_mail_to_commands` configuration option. In our systems, we have it set to `alias, forward` (the default?) which allows delivery to commands to be specified in system-wide alias files and `~/.forward` files.

You can run `postconf` to see what Postfix thinks your configuration is. If `allow_mail_to_commands` is set to something else, changing it in your `main.cf` might be all you need. Otherwise, could you post a (redacted, if you prefer) version of your `main.cf`?